# Animated WebP browser support

Tags: google-chrome, webp

Does Chrome support animated webP? Is there an example of such an image? I'm not finding one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, animation is not stabilized yet and as such not included in Google Chrome yet. [Source](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/d/msg/webp-discuss/D_fUrlSO888/FsTEqLV2Gu4J)

Comment: It's supported now

Comment: To further @bfred.it, Animated WebP support is added to Chrome 32, released January 2014.